# Repeatedly compare same portion of dataset to other portions of dataset based on index value in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, apply, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
state  year  value
1      1980  4
1      1981  5
1      1982  4
2      1980  2
2      1981  3
2      1982  4
100    1980  3
100    1981  2
100    1982  5
```

In the actual dataset, there are more states than are shown here. I would like to make a comparison between state 100 and all other states.

Specifically, for each state, I would like to find the difference between the value given by that state for a particular year and the value given for state 100 for that same year. Below, I have shown how I could compare the value for year 1980 between state 1 and state 100.

```
df_1 <- df %>% filter(state == 1) 
df_100 <- df %>% filter(state == 100)
df_1_1980 <- df_1 %>% filter(year == 1980) 
df_100_1980 <- df_100 %>% filter(year == 1980)
difference <- df_1_1980$value - df_100_1980$value
```

How could I do this for all the other states and years in the dataframe?

One possibility I have considered is making a dataframe composed only of the data from state 100 and then connecting it to the original dataframe, like this:

```
state  year  value  state100  year100  value100
1      1980  4      100       1980     3
1      1981  5      100       1981     2
1      1982  4      100       1982     5
2      1980  2      100       1980     3
2      1981  3      100       1981     2
2      1982  4      100       1982     5
```

I could then subtract df$value from df$value100 for each row. I assume there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `filter` the 'state' that is not equal to 100, `left_join` with the dataset with 'state' 100, `by` 'year' and get the difference between the 'value' columns

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   filter(state != 100) %>% 
   left_join(df %>%
                filter(state == 100) %>% 
                select(-state), by = c('year')) %>% 
   transmute(state, year, value = value.x, difference = value.x - value.y)
#  state year value difference
#1     1 1980     4          1
#2     1 1981     5          3
#3     1 1982     4         -1
#4     2 1980     2         -1
#5     2 1981     3          1
#6     2 1982     4         -1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(state = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 100L, 100L, 
100L), year = c(1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L), value = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 5L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: I think he wants to do year by state, so flip it and do `group_by(year)` and subset value by `state == 100`

Comment: @akrun For this portion of the first solution df$value[df$year == 1980 & df$state == 100], what is happening? Using the example in the original question, the final difference column should be: 1, 3, -1, -1, 1, -1

Comment: @melbez please check the second solution as the first one I kept it because I was not sure what you intended

Comment: @melbez can you check now

Comment: @akrun Where does value.y come from?

Comment: @melbez when there are common column names and that is not used in the `by` column, it will add a suffix `.x`, `.y` to differentiate between the same columns